# Spring Boot : Mock user authentication with security context using Junit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-security

I want to create JUnit 5 test for Rest API which uses JWT token validation:

```
    @Test
    public void resetTokenTest_OK() throws Exception {
        when(userService.findByResetPasswordToken(anyString())).thenReturn(trueOptional);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/users/reset_token")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(ResetPasswordTokenDTO))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.resetPasswordToken").value(randomString_254))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.login").value("login"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status").value("200"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.error").value(""))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.errorDescription").value(""));
    }
```

[GitHub](https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/blob/master/src/test/org/engine/rest/UsersControllerTest.java#L199)

I make a Mockup request using this payload:

```
{
  "resetPasswordToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0.VFb0qJ1LRg_4ujbZoRMXnVkUgiuKq5KxWqNdbKq_G9Vvz-S1zZa9LPxtHWKa64zDl2ofkT8F6jBt_K4riU-fPg",
  "login": "login",
  "status": "1",
  "error": "",
  "errorDescription": ""
}
```

I get NPE for this [line](https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/rest/UsersController.java#L153):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.engine.utils.GenericUtils.getLoggedInUser(GenericUtils.java:15)
    at org.engine.rest.UsersController.lambda$resetToken$0(UsersController.java:159)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:258)
    at org.engine.rest.UsersController.resetToken(UsersController.java:153)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
```

Full [Log](https://pastebin.com/j3ufUNdt):

I get NPE for this code:

```
return (Users) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

[GitHub](https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/blob/2e29cc525f0d87743021f281c63184cd34aa5316/src/main/java/org/engine/utils/GenericUtils.java#L14)

How I can mock the result from `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` in order not to get NPE?

Comment: Don't mock it; use the Spring Security test support (e.g., `@WithUser`) instead.

Comment: Where I need to put it?

Comment: Try putting it above the failing test.

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple ways to mock the security using `@WithMockUser`, `@WithAnonymousUser`, `@WithUserDetails`, `@WithSecurityContext`. You can use these annotations with `@Test` method

---

[**`@WithMockUser`**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withmockuser)

- The user with the username "user" does not have to exist since we are mocking the user
- The Authentication that is populated in the `SecurityContext` is of type `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`
- The principal on the Authentication is Spring Security’s User object
- The User will have the username of *"user"*, the password *"password"*, and a single GrantedAuthority named *"ROLE_USER"* is used.
- You may customize the parameters such as username, roles, value

---

[**`@WithAnonymousUser`**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withanonymoususer)

Using `@WithAnonymousUser` allows running as an anonymous user. This is especially convenient when you wish to run most of your tests with a specific user, but want to run a few tests as an anonymous user. For example, the following will run withMockUser1 and withMockUser2 using `@WithMockUser` and *anonymous as an anonymous user*.

---

[**`@WithUserDetails`**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withuserdetails)

While `@WithMockUser` is a very convenient way to get started, it may *not work* in all instances. For example, it is common for applications to expect that the `Authentication` principal be of a *specific type*. This is done so that the application can refer to the principal as the custom type and reduce coupling on Spring Security.

The custom principal is often times returned by a custom `UserDetailsService` that returns an object that implements both `UserDetails` and the custom type. For situations like this, it is useful to create the test user using the custom UserDetailsService. That is exactly what `@WithUserDetails` does.

---

[**`@WithSecurityContext`**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withsecuritycontext)

We can create our own annotation that uses the @WithSecurityContext to create any SecurityContext we want. For example, we might create an annotation named @WithMockCustomUser as `@WithSecurityContext(factory = WithMockCustomUserSecurityContextFactory.class)`